# Is there any way or tool to check whether a particular iOS app is implementing SSL Pinning functionality?

Tags: openssl, proxy, ios, burp-suite, certificate-pinning

I'm just learning the iOS security. This is completely a beginner question.

I'm trying to figure out whether there is any particular way to check if an iOS app is implementing SSL Pinning functionality.

I've currently checked the SSL traffic of some apps over Burp Proxy. Even after installing Burp Proxy Certificate, some apps are throwing some Alerts, such that there is a fatal error, so the client failed to negotiate an SSL Connection. And I'm not sure whether it is the appropriate way or not.

But what is the exact and perfect way to figure it out ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Using Burp is a good way to test it. But don't forget to import Burp's CA certificate on the device so that it is trusted by the device. Visit `http://burp` in the device's browser and download and install the certificate.

Most apps will now work over SSL and you can see their traffic in Burp. But apps that still fail are doing more checks, i.e. 'pinning'.

You can do the same using [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/). In that case, visit `mitm.it` in the browser to import mitmproxy's CA certificate into your device.

**Edit**
It occurred to me that in Burp, you are not seeing the failed connections that the apps tried to make - you will only see successful ones. What I use to solve that is a tool called `mitmdump`, which is like a basic version of `mitmproxy` (mitdump comes with mitmproxy). It will not only show successful connections but also what SSL connections were refused by the client, so you will know what the app tried to do, and you can see that it was the app that refused to go any further.

Answer (score 0):

SSL pinning implementation can be check or evaluated in two ways.

- Static analysis by inspecting the source code in the Info.list file.
- Follow the link for Apple's guidance on SSL Pinning https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=g9ejcf8y.
- Dynamic analysis using a proxy such as a burp suite or OWAS ZAP.
- Follow the link for iOS device usage with burp suite https://portswigger.net/support/installing-burp-suites-ca-certificate-in-an-ios-device